# should one open new question if old answers no longer work?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to find a way to add control key to automate entering [[ and ]]

But the answers here [automating-esc-esc-formatting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/automating-esc-esc-formatting) do not work on 11.2 on windows any more. I've been trying for 20 minutes and they have no effect.

Should one in this case open a new question and add link to the old one? Just adding a comment below one of the answer in the above is not going to be noticed by any one.

It seems something changed and these short cuts no longer work in 11.2 on windows.

Comment: Edit the question itself, I'd say. Maybe put up an `###UPDATE <insert date here>: None of the current answers work in 11.2` or something.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think I favor posting a new question rather than editing the old one on the principle of "not moving the goal posts."  The existing answers are no less valid for the version(s) for which they were written, even if something fundamental has changed in the key handing in v11.2.

It seems to me sufficient and superior to create a new question and then insert a link to it in the older one, e.g. "For versions 11.2+ see:" etc.